# Fedora Is Asking For Username and password at boot

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, passwords

When I turn my computer on GRUB auto loads fedora and I get Username:
then Password: and when i type them in  i get error: access denied Failed to boot both default and fallback entries then i get GRUB if Grub dosen't Auto-Boot it (e.g I press Enter) I get Username:, Password: Like before but not the error it just goes straight back to Grub

DETAILS: Fedora 17, GNU Grub version 2.00~beta6

Even logging in as Root wont work ( I think my computer is dodgy Windows=BSOD Ubuntu=Internet Not Work Linux Mint=Wouldn't Do Sound Fedora 17= Best So Far Only re installed 4 times Fedora 18 alpha= Formatted My Pictures Away -_-)

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if you mistype the password (i.e., used CapsLock when creating the account, or sometimes when using non-ASCII characters in the password you might be entering it with one keyboard layout while graphical login uses another). What you can do is to start the machine in single user mode (add `single` to the kernel line when booting) and set th passwords there to *only* ASCII (to prevent any of the mentioned problems), and try again.

Another possibility I've seen is that the account name is invalid, but accepted anyway to create the account. It should be 8 letter or digits, at least start with a letter, purely ASCII.